# How to effectively manage queue transactions listened by two ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I have made two ec2 instances listening to one particular aws sqs queue. Now both the instances are connected via load balancer. The problem is , as both the instances are listening on the same queue, isn't the message going to be received by both the instances at the same time. If it is received on both the instances at the same time, how to prevent duplication of the transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your architecture does not describe a normal usage pattern for Amazon SQS.

**Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)** is a queueing service where you can create a **queue** and send **messages** to a queue. Amazon SQS retains the message for up to 14 days.

Applications can then request to **receive** a message from the queue. This makes the message **invisible** while the application is processing the message. Once the application finishes processing the message, to tells SQS to **delete** the message from the queue. If the application fails while processing a message, Amazon SQS will make the message **visible** again after a period of time so that it can be processed by another application server.

Things to note:

- SQS **does not send messages**. Rather, applications request to **receive** a message from the queue. Think of the apps as "retrieving" a message rather than SQS transmitting a message.
- The instances retrieving the messages **should not be sitting behind a Load Balancer**. There is nothing sent to a Load Balancer in this process. Instead, the instances themselves connect to SQS and request a message.
- If you wish to send a message to multiple systems at the same time, you can use **Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)**.

Comment: I am not sending messages from sqs to any instances. What I am saying, is that both the instances are listening to the same queue.

Comment: Instances don't "listen" to a queue. Rather, they make a `RetrieveMessages` call to the queue to ask for 1-10 messages. If a message is returned, then that message is marked invisible and is not supplied to any other SQS client (unless there is a timeout and the message reappears on the queue). Therefore, a message will only go to one instance, as a result of the instance asking for a message. There is no Load Balancer involved.

Comment: Yes, by listening, I intend to say that if both the instance are working at the same time and calling `RetrieveMessages ` , don't you think both will get the message at the same time, because visibility period is useful when the processes are sequential but here they are parallel.

Comment: There is a very, very small chance that the same message will be returned by simultaneous calls to `RetrieveMessages`. It is unlikely, but in high-volume systems processing hundreds or thousands of messages per second, it can happen. This is not the case for [SQS First-In First-Out (FIFO) queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html), but they have speed limitations. In general, if double-processing a message is undesirable for your system, you should add some form of checking to avoid double-processing (eg check for unique IDs).